# Inserting if loop within awk

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

I had a problem solved in a previous post using the awk, but now I want to put an if loop in it, but I am getting an error.

Here's the problem:

I had a lot of files that looked like this:

```
 Header
 175566717.000
 175570730.000
 175590376.000
 175591966.000
 175608932.000
 175612924.000
 175614836.000
 .
 .
 .
 175680016.000
 175689679.000
 175695803.000
 175696330.000
```

And I wanted to extract the first 2000 lines (line 1 to 2000), then extract the lines 1500 to 3500, then 3000 to 5000 and so on... What I mean is: extract a window of 2000 lines with an overlap of 500 lines between contiguous windows until the end of the file.

This is the awk command used for it:

```
awk -v i=1 -v t=2000 -v d=501 'NR>1{a[NR-1]=$0}END{
    while(i<NR-1){
        ++n;
        for(k=i;k<i+t;k++)print a[k] > "win"n".txt"; 
        close("_win"n".txt") 
        i=i+t-d
    }

}' myfile.txt
done
```

And I get several files with names win1.txt , win2.txt , win3.txt , etc...

My problem now is that because the file was not a multiple of 2000, my last window has less than 2000 lines. How can I put an if loop that would do this: if the last window had less than 2000 digital numbers, the previous window should had all the lines until the end of the file.

EXTRA INFO

When the windows are created, there is a line break at the end.That is why I needed the if loop to take into account a window of less than 2000 digital numbers, and not just lines.

Comment: A quick and dirty way, would be to do it afterwards (outside of `awk` but in the `bash` script). Get the filenames of the last 2 files, run `wc` on the last file and apply your test, if it's less than 2000 `cat` it to the second to last file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want an overlap between files? Good luck.

Comment: @TimothyBrown thanks, that might work. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for some other reason, try the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) approach

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$(sed '/^\s*$/d' myfile.txt)"
sed -n 1,2000p <<< "$file"
first=1500
last=3500
max=$(wc -l <<< "$file" | awk '{print $1}')
while [[ $max -ge 2000 && $last -lt $((max+1500)) ]]; do
  sed -n "$first","$last"p <<< "$file"
  ((first+=1500))
  ((last+=1500))
done
```

Obviously this is going to be less fast than [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and more error prone for gigatic files, but should work in most cases.

Comment: But this would spawn sed 1+N times as opposed to spawning awk once.

Comment: Where N=#_of_lines/2000, sure. Didn't say [tag:sed] would be faster than [tag:awk]

Comment: Why read the file into memory?  Instead of using `<<< "$file"` to read from a string, just read from the file each time.  The OS will cache the file in memory as well as your program will, so there should be no noticeable difference in performance.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Not a performance decision, couldn't figure out a simple way to both ignore empty lines and consider some line range at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `while` condition to make it stop earlier:

```
while (i+t <= NR) {
```

Change the end condition of the `for` loop to compensate for the last output file being potentially bigger:

```
for (k = i; k < (i+t+t-d <= NR ? i+t : NR); k++)
```

The rest of your code can stay the same; although I took the liberty of removing the `close` statement (why was that?), and to set `d=500`, to make the output files *really* overlap by 500 lines.

```
awk -v i=1 -v t=2000 -v d=500 'NR>1{a[NR-1]=$0}END{
    while (i+t <= NR) {
        ++n;
        for (k=i; k < (i+t+t-d <= NR ? i+t : NR); k++) print a[k] > "win"n".txt"; 
        i=i+t-d
    }
}' myfile.txt
```

I tested it with small values of `t` and `d`, and it seems to work as requested.

One final remark: for big input files, I wouldn't encourage storing the whole thing in array `a`.